# How to convert values in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to convert the values from the column `Debit`; if the values is blank it should convert to `0` otherwise it should convert the value to a decimal.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
  CONVERT(Decimal(18, 2), (CASE Debit WHEN ' ' THEN 0 END)
```

It works, but I want to retain the value if its not a blank. How would I do that?

Comment: did not get what you are trying to do .. please elaborate

Comment: try this
`CONVERT(Decimal(18, 2), REPLACE(Debit, ' ', '0'))`
suggested by ahillier88

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
CONVERT(Decimal(18, 2), REPLACE(Debit, ' ', '0'))
```

Comment: yeah..something like that..tnx buddy